# Let  be a regular language. Prove all minimal automata for the language are isomorphic

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

I have started to study formal languages, especially finite automata and regular languages and I encountered some difficulties, i.e. Is this true:

Automata will be called isomorphic if, by changing the names of the states, one moves from one automaton to the second.
Let  be a regular language. How can I Prove that all minimal automata for the language are isomorphic?

Thank you for any hints and answers!

Comment: Your question is equivalent to the uniqueness of "the" minimal DFA. See references [2] and [3] of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization

Comment: @erfink How would I have connected each minimal automaton with different names for states to prove this?